# How to make a personalised ruler?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, code, sourcecode

I wanted to know if and how would it be possible to create a personalised ruler in LaTeX.

"Personalised" means I would like to create something like the "famous" IMPERFECTO ruler, where I can define and set the ticks, the numbers and maybe creating something "fancy" (like alternating numbers and ticks and so on).

To give you the IMPERFECTO example: here.

[IMPERFECTO RULER](https://www.kleinbottle.com/imperfecto.html)

Where you can see two $17$s, and $9$ millimiters instead of $10$ between the two seventeens.

Comment: No one? How is that possible?

Comment: Use the `picture` environment or maybe there is a `tikz` solution.